# Python 3- Writing dictionaries with dictionary values to CSV files

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I've tried google- but I've not been able to find a solution that works with dictionaries with dictionary values. Let me explain a little simpler.

I have a dictionary of Ticket Codes, and with each ticket code is another dictionary, containing 'name' and 'redeemed'- name being the ticket owner and redeemed being whether the ticket has been redeemed. The data is loaded from a csv file named TicketCodes, which contains 1000 lines of this data. I have a system that will truncate the file ready for writing, but the solutions I have found for writing to a CSV don't work. I apologize if this is a duplicate- I may not have searched hard enough. If it is, please can you link me to a solution? Thank you very much!

Comment: Please show the code you have tried and the errors you got.

Comment: First of all pay attention to the comment above mine. After that, querying my crystal ball I supposed that a proper serialization format for your data structure could be a JSON (you have a dictionary whose values are dictionary).

Comment: Dictionary of tickets? So its in fact a collection? If so, what is the key and do you need to store it? Better give a sample entry for completion.

Comment: Ok, the data I am writing looks a little like this: '{data1: {data11: 'value', data12: 'value'}}'

Comment: Can you give an example of both what your dict looks like and what you want the CSV file to look like? My solution will work for what I have assumed the data to look like but could be tweaked to match your data, assuming CSV is an appropriate format in the first place.

Comment: Ok, so my dictionary looks like this: ticketdict = {'code1': {'name': '', 'redeemed': 'false'}, 'code2': ...} and so on. All keys and values, even header titles and the redeemed values are just strings. The CSV's first line will be the column titles, ticketid,name,redeemed and the following lines will continue this format.

Comment: So my question is, how could I write this data into a CSV?

Answer (score 0):

JSON would be a much better format for writing out Python dict data. However, if all of your dict's have the same keys then you could potentially format a CSV document with the dict key's as the column names.

**For example:**

```
# Assuming the data is a list of dictionaries
the_data = [{'col1': 'data1', 'col2': 'data2'},
            {'col1': 'data3', 'col2': 'data4'},
            {'col1': 'data5', 'col2': 'data6'},
            {'col1': 'data7', 'col2': 'data8'}]

# Build a list of the column names.
# This could be done with list(the_data[0].keys())
# But then you have no control over the column ordering
column_names = ['col1', 'col2']

# Print out column names
print(",".join(column_names))

# Print out data
for row in the_data:
    print(",".join([row[field] for field in column_names]))
```

**Output:**

```
col1,col2
data1,data2
data3,data4
data5,data6
data7,data8
```

Note: In my example I have just printed out the CSV data but it would be trivial to write this data to a file.

Also, to write `the_data` to JSON format it is as simple as doing the following:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(the_data)

'[{"col2": "data2", "col1": "data1"}, {"col2": "data4", "col1": "data3"}, {"col2": "data6", "col1": "data5"}, {"col2": "data8", "col1": "data7"}]'
```

Comment: `"You have no control over column ordering"` Incorrect, this can be done by `from collections import OrderedDict` and create an `OrderedDict()` for each `{}`. Create an `OrderedDict()` for each element of the list then add a few lines of code to put keys and values

Comment: @ytpillai you are right, but the original question did say that this dict is being passed to them from somewhere else, they might not have the control over the data type. Also having a list of column names would let you write out a subset easily as well.

Comment: How would they not have control over the dictionary?